# Allocation / Weighted Average question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm hoping someone can help with my problem.  Forgive me as I don't even know what title to give this.  I'm trying to come up with an allocation method for transportation expenses for multiple stops along a truck route based on a combination of mileage and cargo weight.  I'm not sure if this is possible based on the known variables/constants.

I'll lay out an example:

3 stops all forming a straight line from a shipping location, the farthest point being 50 miles from the shipping location.

Stop 1: 10 miles from starting point, 10,000 lbs

Stop 2: 40 miles from starting point (30 miles from stop 1), 30,000 lbs

Stop 3: 50 miles from starting point (10 miles from stop 2), 20,000 lbs

Rules and/or known items, if you will:
Total miles to allocate = 50 (maximum value/farthest point of all of the stops)

Total weight = 60,000 lbs of cargo.

Each stop's allocation amount cannot be greater than the mileage for that stop (i.e. stop # 2 cannot have more than 40 miles allocated.)

You can't look at the mileage between the stops because that's not a fair allocation method.  Stop 3 shouldn't only be charged for 10 miles when it made up of 33% of the weight.

Something like the following is easy to figure out based on simple logic:

Stop 1: 25 miles 10,000 lbs

Stop 2: 25 miles 20,000 lbs (drop off point is the same location as stop 1, the only variable is weight)

Solution:

Stop 1: 25 * (10,000/30,000 total weight) = 8.33 miles

Stop 2: 25 * (20,000/30,000 total weight) = 16.67 miles

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.  I'm assuming I would at least have to determine how to weight the mileage vs. the cargo weight at the very least.  Let's say that cargo weight is 2x as important as the mileage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many formulas that will give an answer. You need to specify what you are looking for.  One simpleminded approach is to bill each stop for its share of the load for each segment that it is part of.  So stop $1$ had $\frac 16$ of the load for $10$ miles, so pays $\frac {10}6$.  Stop $2$ had $\frac 12$ of the load for $10$ miles and $\frac 35$ of the load for $30$ miles, so pays $\frac {10}2+ \frac {3 \cdot 30}5=23$  Stop $3$ has $\frac 13$ of $10$ miles, $\frac 25$ of $30$ and all of $10$, so pays $\frac {10}3+\frac {2\cdot 30}5+10=25\frac 13$

Comment: Hi Ross, I think you nailed it.  I read your answer and I think "Of course, why didn't I figure that out."  Now I just need to turn this into an Excel formula and I'll be good to go.  The scenario could change in terms of number of stops, miles, and weight of each, but the same logic should work regardless of the situation.  Thanks a million!